# Alamofire request blocking during application lifecycle

Tags: ios, alamofire, nsoperationqueue, operation

I'm having troubles with Alamofire using `Operation` and `OperationQueue`.

I have an `OperationQueue` named `NetworkingQueue` and I push some operation (wrapping AlamofireRequest) into it, everything works fine, but during application living, at one moment all Alamofire request are not sent. My queue is getting bigger and bigger and no request go to the end.

I do not have a scheme to reproduce it anytime.

Does anybody have a clue for helping me?

Here is a sample of code

The BackgroundAlamoSession

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "[...].background")
self.networkingSessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

AbstractOperation.swift

```
import UIKit
import XCGLogger

class AbstractOperation:Operation {

    private let _LOGGER:XCGLogger = XCGLogger.default

    enum State:String {
        case Ready = "ready"
        case Executing = "executing"
        case Finished = "finished"

        var keyPath: String {
            get{
                return "is" + self.rawValue.capitalized
            }
        }
    }

    override var isAsynchronous:Bool {
        get{
            return true
        }
    }

    var state = State.Ready {
        willSet {
            willChangeValue(forKey: self.state.rawValue)
            willChangeValue(forKey: self.state.keyPath)
            willChangeValue(forKey: newValue.rawValue)
            willChangeValue(forKey: newValue.keyPath)
        }
        didSet {
            didChangeValue(forKey: oldValue.rawValue)
            didChangeValue(forKey: oldValue.keyPath)
            didChangeValue(forKey: self.state.rawValue)
            didChangeValue(forKey: self.state.keyPath)
        }
    }


    override var isExecuting: Bool {
        return state == .Executing
    }

    override var isFinished:Bool {
        return state == .Finished
    }

}
```

A concrete Operation implementation

```
import UIKit
import XCGLogger
import SwiftyJSON

class FetchObject: AbstractOperation {

    public let _LOGGER:XCGLogger = XCGLogger.default

    private let _objectId:Int
    private let _force:Bool

    public var object:ObjectModel?


    init(_ objectId:Int, force:Bool) {
        self._objectId = objectId
        self._force = force
    }

    convenience init(_ objectId:Int) {
        self.init(objectId, force:false)
    }

    override var desc:String {
        get{
            return "FetchObject(\(self._objectId))"
        }
    }

    public override func start(){
        self.state = .Executing
    _LOGGER.verbose("Fetch object operation start")

        if !self._force {
            let objectInCache:objectModel? = Application.main.collections.availableObjectModels[self._objectId]

            if let objectInCache = objectInCache {
                _LOGGER.verbose("object with id \(self._objectId) founded on cache")
                self.object = objectInCache
                self._LOGGER.verbose("Fetch object operation end : success")
                self.state = .Finished
                return
            }
        }

        if !self.isCancelled {

            let url = "[...]\(self._objectId)"

            _LOGGER.verbose("Requesting object with id \(self._objectId) on server")

            Application.main.networkingSessionManager.request(url, method : .get)
                .validate()
                .responseJSON(
                    completionHandler: { response in
                        switch response.result {
                        case .success:
                            guard let raw:Any = response.result.value else {
                                self._LOGGER.error("Error while fetching json programm : Empty response")
                                self._LOGGER.verbose("Fetch object operation end : error")
                                self.state = .Finished
                                return
                            }
                            let data:JSON = JSON(raw)
                            self._LOGGER.verbose("Received object from server \(data["bId"])")
                            self.object = ObjectModel(objectId:data["oId"].intValue,data:data)
                            Application.main.collections.availableobjectModels[self.object!.objectId] = self.object
                            self._LOGGER.verbose("Fetch object operation end : success")
                            self.state = .Finished
                            break
                        case .failure(let error):
                            self._LOGGER.error("Error while fetching json program \(error)")
                            self._LOGGER.verbose("Fetch object operation end : error")
                            self.state = .Finished
                            break
                        }
                })
        } else {
            self._LOGGER.verbose("Fetch object operation end : cancel")
            self.state = .Finished
        }
    }
}
```

The NetworkQueue

```
class MyQueue {
    public static let networkQueue:SaootiQueue = SaootiQueue(name:"NetworkQueue", concurent:true)
}
```

How I use it in another operation and wait for for result

```
let getObjectOperation:FetchObject = FetchObject(30)
SaootiQueue.networkQueue.addOperations([getObjectOperation], waitUntilFinished: true)
```

How I use it the main operation using KVO

```
let getObjectOperation:FetchObject = FetchObject(30)

operation.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Operation.isFinished), options: [.new], context: nil)
operation.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Operation.isCancelled), options: [.new], context: nil)

queue.addOperation(operation)

//[...]

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

    if let operation = object as? FetchObject {

    operation.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Operation.isFinished))
    operation.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(Operation.isCancelled))

    if keyPath == #keyPath(Operation.isFinished) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

---

A few clarifications:

My application is a radio player and I need, while playing music and the background, to fetch the currently playing program. This is why I need background Session.

In fact I also use the background session for all the networking I do when the app is foreground. Should I avoid that ?

The wait I'm using is from another queue and is never used in the main queue (I know it is a threading antipattern and I take care of it).

In fact it is used when I do two networking operation and the second one depends of the result of the second. I put a wait after the first operation to avoid KVO observing. Should I avoid that ?

---

Additional edit:

When I say "My queue is getting bigger and bigger and no request go to the end", it means that at one moment during application livecycle, random for the moment (I can not find a way to reproduce it at every time), Alamofire request don't reach the response method.

Because of that the `Operation` wrapper don't end and the queue is growing.

By the way I'm working on converting Alamofire request into `URLRequest` for having clues and I founded some problem on using the main queue. I have to sort what is due to the fact that Alamofire use the main queue for reponse method and I'll see if I find a potential deadlock

I'll keep you informed. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added some sample code . I hope it will provide 
 more information and if something wrong is in detect it.

Comment: What is `operation.first`? I don't see any `first` property...

Comment: It's my bad when provided the code I tried to remove all business code to focus on the problem. First is a part of business code. In fact all operation are overload to make a different request. first parameter is on the overload class. I remove it from sample code

Comment: If you are 100% sure that are situations where it's getting to the `request`, but you're not seeing `responseJSON` called, the only thing that I know of that could cause that would be a deadlock. But that would cause the UI to lock up and for anything not on the main thread to freeze. Or if you set some exceptionally large timeout parameter, it might appear to not run the closure. Or if you had some path in your operation that didn't set the `state` to finished or canceled, your queue would back up. It's hard to say w/out [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

There are minor issues, but this operation implementation looks largely correct. Sure, you should make your state management thread-safe, and there are other stylistic improvements you could make, but I don't think this is critical to your question.

1. What looks worrisome is `addOperations(_:waitUntilFinished:)`. From which queue are you waiting? If you do that from the main queue, you will deadlock (i.e. it will look like the Alamofire requests never finish). Alamofire uses the main queue for its completion handlers (unless you override the `queue` parameter of `responseJSON`), but if you're waiting on the main thread, this can never take place. (As an aside, if you can refactor so you never explicitly "wait" for operations, that not only avoids the deadlock risk, but is a better pattern in general.)
2. I also notice that you're using Alamofire requests wrapped in operations in conjunction with a background session. Background sessions are antithetical to operations and completion handler closure patterns. Background sessions continue after your app has been jettisoned and you have to rely solely upon the `SessionDelegate` closures that you set when you first configure your `SessionManager` when the app starts. When the app restarts, your operations and completion handler closures are long gone.

   Bottom line, do you really need background session (i.e. uploads and downloads that continue after your app terminates)? If so, you may want to lose this completion handler and operation based approach. If you don't need this to continue after the app terminates, don't use background sessions. Configuring Alamofire to properly handle background sessions is a non-trivial exercise, so only do so if you absolutely need to. Remember to not conflate background sessions and the simple asynchronous processing that Alamofire (and `URLSession`) do automatically for you.

---

You asked:

> My application is a radio player and I need, while playing music and the background, to fetch the currently playing program. This is why I need background Session.

You need background sessions if you want downloads to proceed while the app is not running. If your app is running in the background, though, playing music, you probably don't *need* background sessions. But, if the user chooses to download a particular media asset, you may well want background session so that the download proceeds when the user leaves the app, whether the app is playing music or not.

> In fact I also use the background session for all the networking I do when the app is foreground. Should I avoid that ?

It's fine. It's a little slower, IIRC, but it's fine.

The problem isn't that you're using background session, but that you're doing it wrong. The operation-based wrapping of Alamofire doesn't make sense with a background session. For sessions to proceed in the background, you are constrained as to how you use `URLSession`, namely:

- You cannot use data tasks while the app is not running; only upload and download tasks.
- You cannot rely upon completion handler closures (because the entire purpose of background sessions is to keep them running when your app terminates and then fire up your app again when they're done; but if the app was terminated, your closures are all gone).

  You have to use delegate based API only for background sessions, not completion handlers.
- You have to implement the app delegate method to capture the system provided completion handler that you call when you're done processing background session delegate calls. You have to call that when your `URLSession` tells you that it's done processing all the background delegate methods.

All of this is a significant burden, IMHO. Given that the system is keeping you app alive for background music, you might contemplate using a standard `URLSessionConfiguration`. If you're going to use background session, you might need to refactor all of this completion handler-based code.

> The wait I'm using is from another queue and is never used in the main queue (I know it is a threading antipattern and I take care of it).

Good. There's still serious code smell from ever using "wait", but if you are 100% confident that it's not deadlocking here, you can get away with it. But it's something you really should check (e.g. put some logging statement after the "wait" and make sure you're getting past that line, if you haven't already confirmed this).

> In fact it is used when I do two networking operation and the second one depends of the result of the second. I put a wait after the first operation to avoid KVO observing. Should I avoid that ?

Personally, I'd lose that KVO observing and just establish `addDependency` between the operations. Also, if you get rid of that KVO observing, you can get rid of your double KVO notification process. But I don't think this KVO stuff is the root of the problem, so maybe you defer that.